# how to reduce execution time of multiple query

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

there are so many queryies with millions of data and execution of queries taking so much time almost 10 min.I dont know how to reduce the execution time.
suppose this is a query like this there are almost more then 15 queries
is there is any chance to reduce execution time

```
currentmonth80days= "select count(distinct(retail_str_sales_detail.sale_date)) as DAY,retail_str_sales_detail.store_id as STORE_ID,round(sum(total),2) AS TOTAL,retail_store.str_nm AS STORES,
count(distinct(tri_id)) as BILLS from retail_str_sales_detail,retail_store where  retail_str_sales_detail.store_id = retail_store.store_id and  retail_str_sales_detail.sale_date
between first_day(current_date) and current_date  group by retail_store.str_nm,retail_str_sales_detail.store_id
having count(distinct(retail_str_sales_detail.sale_date)) >=  ((( day(current_date)*80)/100)) order by retail_store.str_nm";
querycurrentmonth80days= dbGetQuery(conn,currentmonth80days)
bizcurrentMonth80days= data.frame(
  Stores= querycurrentmonth80days$STR_NM,
  Day= querycurrentmonth80days$DAY,
  Bills = querycurrentmonth80days$BILLS,
  Total= as.numeric(as.character(querycurrentmonth80days$TOTAL)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Query Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801188/sql-query-optimization)

Comment: You mention Shiny; You could place them in global.r so they only run once when the app starts. Whenever a user connects, the dataframes are already in memory, see [scoping](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html). I am voting to close this question though, because it is too broad (and there are already questions on SQL query optimization)